# NetCore project shows managed dlls from nuget package directly under project root level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have created Nuget package that contains third party dlls.
(It targets netstandard2.0 and net462)

The dlls are under "build" level in the nuget package together with "MyLib.targets" file.

Under "lib" level is MyLib.dll.

If I use nuget package with net462 project all looks and works fine.
The dll are not visible in the project and will be copied to the output directory(thanks to the .targets file).

If I create NetCore2.0 project and use my package, it works fine and dlls are copied to the output directory, but
all dlls (12 of them) will be visible in VS under the root of the project.
So my Program.cs file ends up in the middle of the dll hell.

If I try to remove them I get message:
Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file .... .targets.

Is there a way to hide third party dlls that came with my Nuget package from the Visual Studio project?

.targets file is the snippet from stack overflow:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.*" Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.targets" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Visible` metadata to `false` to tell VS to not display the item in the solution explorer:

```
<None Include="…">
  …
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</None>
```

See [Common MSBuild Project Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items) for documentation on the metadata attributes.

Comment: this works, thanks. Unfortunately *.dll does not work, but I need to specify each file manually.

Comment: From the example above? if you do a `<None Update="..." …/>` you'd need to specify a wildcard that matches the identity, so using `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` again